# make validation on the uploaded file with laravel

Tags: laravel, validation

how can i add validation roles to the file, in this example here:

```
public function store( Product $product, Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'info' => ['required'],
            'min' =>['required'],
            'max' => ['required'],
            'file' => ['nullable', 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,PNG,doc,docx,pdf,xsl,xlsx'],
        ]);

        //store
        if($request->hasFile('file')) {
            $dest_path = 'public/orders/files';
            $order_file = $request->file('file');
            $file_name = time().'.'.$order_file->getClientOriginalName();
            $order_file->storeAs($dest_path, $file_name);

            try {
                Order::create([
                    'info' => $request->info,
                    'min' => $request->min,
                    'max' => $request->max,
                    'file' => $file_name,
                    'product_id' => $product->id,
                    'user_id' => auth()->id(),
                    'owner_id' => $product->user->id
                ])->save();
```

in the method above it doesn't working...

and this is the .blade file:

```
 <form action="{{route('order.store', [$product->id])}}" method="post"
                      enctype="multipart/form-data" class="">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="px-4 py-5 sm:p-6 items-center justify-center mb-5">
                        <label for="info" class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">Details</label>
                        <textarea rows="5" name="info" id="info"
                                  class="rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full p-5"
                                  placeholder="write any information about your order"></textarea>
                        @error('info')
                        <p class="text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</p>
                        @enderror
                    </div>


                    <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6">
                        <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3 mb-6 md:mb-0">
                            <label class="block tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="grid-name">
                                Minimum Period (in Days)
                            </label>
                            <input name="min" value="{{old('min')}}" class="@error('min') border-red-500 @enderror appearance-none block w-full bg-white text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white" id="grid-first-name" type="number" placeholder="30">
                            @error('min')
                            <p class="text-red-500 text-xs italic">{{$message}}</p>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3">
                            <label class="block  tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="grid-email">
                                Maximum Period (in Days)
                            </label>
                            <input name="max" value="{{old('max')}}" class="@error('max') border-red-500 @enderror appearance-none block w-full bg-white text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500" id="grid-email" type="number" placeholder="40">
                            @error('max')
                            <p class="text-red-500 text-xs italic">{{$message}}</p>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="bg-gray-100 text-center justify-center text-black
                    font-bold border border-red-600 p-5 mb-10">
                        send a word, pdf, text or image file contains all information about your order, like information
                        about yourself, if your order is CV, or information, digrams and images ..etc.. about the
                        application if your order is application.
                    </div>

                    <div class="flex w-full h-20 items-center justify-center bg-grey-lighter">
                        <label
                            class="w-64 flex flex-col items-center px-4 py-6 bg-white text-blue rounded-lg shadow-lg tracking-wide uppercase border border-blue cursor-pointer hover:bg-blue hover:text-white">
                            <svg class="w-8 h-8" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                 viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path
                                    d="M16.88 9.1A4 4 0 0 1 16 17H5a5 5 0 0 1-1-9.9V7a3 3 0 0 1 4.52-2.59A4.98 4.98 0 0 1 17 8c0 .38-.04.74-.12 1.1zM11 11h3l-4-4-4 4h3v3h2v-3z"/>
                            </svg>
                            <span class="mt-2 text-base leading-normal">Select a file</span>
                            <input type='file' name="file" class="hidden"/>
                        </label>
                    </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: try this format `'order_file' => 'nullable|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,PNG,doc,docx,pdf,xsl,xlsx'`

Comment: same issue... the problem not in format, because others are works, just for file

Comment: Are you sending file via FormData (JQuery) ?

Comment: no, just laravel php

Comment: @OsamaMohammed can you show blade file code

Comment: yes, i have updated the question with blade file

Comment: it was my fault, i had a problem with input file name... thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you have to check:

1. Does your form have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?
2. Check your file field name. Is it`file`?

Comment: it was my fault, i had a problem in the input file name>>>> thank you